# Can this be script simplified

Tags: jquery

Here is part of a script i'm running to detach and then append some tab content based on the ID of the tab being selected , and also i need to use url indexOf when linking from another page to the tab content directly.

here is what i have working , but i have 20-30 of these in order , wanted to know if it could be shortened down

```
// TAB 1 AND CONTENT TAB 1
   var mfltab1 = $('#tabcontent1 #homepagecolumns').detach();
    $('li#tab1').one('click',function(){
       $('#tabcontent1').append(mfltab1);
    });
    if ( document.location.href.indexOf('#1') > -1 ) {
       $('#tabcontent1').append(mfltab1);
    }

// TAB 2 AND CONTENT TAB 2
   var mfltab2 = $('#tabcontent2 #homepagecolumns').detach();
    $('li#tab2').one('click',function(){
       $('#tabcontent2').append(mfltab2);
    });
    if ( document.location.href.indexOf('#2') > -1 ) {
       $('#tabcontent2').append(mfltab2);
    }
```

and so goes on for TAB 3 , TAB 4 ......up to TAB 20

I tried this suggestion , but its not working , I may have it marked up incorrectly ?

```
$(document).ready ( function(){ 
  var mfltab = [
    $('#tabcontent1 #homepagecolumns').detach(),
    $('#tabcontent2 #homepagecolumns').detach(),
    $('#tabcontent3 #homepagecolumns').detach(),
    $('#tabcontent4 #homepagecolumns').detach(),
    $('#tabcontent5 #homepagecolumns').detach(),
    $('#tabcontent6 #homepagecolumns').detach(),
    $('#tabcontent7 #homepagecolumns').detach(),
    $('#tabcontent8 #homepagecolumns').detach(),
    $('#tabcontent9 #homepagecolumns').detach(),
    $('#tabcontent10 #homepagecolumns').detach()
  ];

  for(var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    $('li#tab' + i).one('click',function(){
        $('#tabcontent' + i).append(mfltab[i]);
    });
    if ( document.location.href.indexOf('#' + i) > -1 ) {
        $('#tabcontent' + i).append(mfltab[i]);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: This question could be suitable for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help), as long as (a) your code works as intended, (b) your code is real code, rather than example code, and (c) your code is included in the body of the question. If you wish for a peer review to improve all aspects of your code, please post it on Code Review.

Comment: You are repeating ID's and they must be unique in a page. Your code is prone to fail as a result

Comment: @charlietfl jQuery does not care as he has them scoped... It's definately not best practice, but completely valid.

Answer (score 2):

Yes... use an array for the tabs

```
var mfltab =[mfltab1, mfltab2, ..., mfltab20];
```

or

```
var mfltab = [
    $('#tabcontent1 #homepagecolumns').detach(),
    ....
    $('#tabcontent20 #homepagecolumns').detach()
];
```

Then use string concatenation:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    $('li#tab' + i).one('click',function(){
        $('#tabcontent' + i).append(mfltab[i]);
    });
    if ( document.location.href.indexOf('#' + i) > -1 ) {
        $('#tabcontent' + i).append(mfltab[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: when setting up the var , how do i add this to it  var mfltab1 = $('#tabcontent1 #homepagecolumns').detach();  for each one ?

Comment: ty Ryan , i updated my question with your answer and how i have it implemented , its not working at all for me , though the long version was . I may have it marked up incorrectly ?

Comment: Oh, is your index messed up? I zero indexed... You are 1 indexed. Ex: `for(var i = 1; i <= 20; i++)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101631/discussion-between-ryan0319-and-mshack).